# Python project use .so library, but i don't understand how it works

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries

I inherited the project. I am not very experienced in this kind of issues, so please tell me where to read more, or give at least some advice. I've gone through the entire internet.
The project works, but I don't understand how)

I have a run.py file that imports the plib.so package, but I can't figure out exactly how it works. I also know that there is a separate requirements.txt file for this library to work, which is driving me crazy. I don't understand how a compiled library can use the normal Python package dependencies.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naxp3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0ZcE.png)

I tried to look up similar usage of so packages on the internet but couldn't find anything suitable for my case.

Comment: The `.so` files are shared libraries in Unix. The equivalent on Windows would be a `.dll` file.

Your Python program is loading the `plib.so` shared library at runtime, which might be using the Python-C API to provide new Python classes, functions, or even to interact with an existing C or C++ library. This is done using Python's `ctype`, `ctypes`, or `cffi` libraries usually.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

According to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/plib/), plib is `A namespace package for a number of useful sub-packages and modules.`

It appears to be a utility library. This section summarizes well why you would use the library:

> The general philosophy of PLIB is to do everything possible in pure Python, so the only functions that appear in this sub-package are those which by their very nature cannot be done in pure Python. The fdtools module provides utilities for working with file descriptors.

One of the sub-packages is a  GUI application framework, but without more information on the contents of your `run.py` file, I can't tell which other sub-packages your application uses.